# What is the sender in RemoteCertificateValidationCallback?

Tags: .net

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` is a property of type `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback`.  The constructor for `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` takes a delegate such as

```
public bool SomeCertificateErrorHandler(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return false; // Don't accept any certificates!
}
```

When this delegate is called, what specific type is `sender`?  If it isn't obvious from that answer, what use is `sender` in this delegate?

(Just so there is no confusion, I was being facetious regarding the contents of the method.  I'm interested in the parameters.)

Answer (score 2):

Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx) (emphasis added):

> When doing custom validation, the sender parameter passed to the
>   RemoteCertificateValidationCallback can be **a host string name** or **an
>   object derived from WebRequest** (HttpWebRequest, for example) depending
>   on the CertificatePolicy property.

For example, the sender's RequestUri.Host could be validated against a list of host names.